# Find the area of the circle

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, parametric

Find the area of the circle defined by the parametric equations $x = \cos t$ and $y = \sin t$.

I know this is circle defined by $x^2 +y^2 =1$ so i used  $0 < t < 2\pi$ as my bounds, then integrated $\cos^2t$ and got my answer as $\pi$, this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Since $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ we see that the parameterized circle has radius $r = 1$, and consequently has area $\pi r^2 = \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as
$$
A = \int_{0}^1\int_0^{2\pi} r\ {\rm d}\theta\ {\rm d}r = \pi.
$$

Comment: i dont see why i need the integral from 0 to 1, what does that do?

Comment: The radius has to sweep out the entire disk.

Comment: This is just an idea! :)

Comment: @AdamHughes: Yes!